# How do I add logging on salesforce app in 2nd generation managed code?

Tags: app, logging, second-generation-packaging, support

How do I add logging on salesforce app? Assuming it would not be a good idea to aggregate logs to external system, if we do add logs it is going to sit in the customer's salesforce org. What is the best way to add logs such that if something goes wrong our support team can grab those logs to investigate the issue?

Comment: Can you **[edit]** your post to clarify if you are posting this question about managed package development specifically?

Comment: It would be good to tag the question at the same time.

Comment: I updated my question as 2nd generation managed code. Our technical support contact person from salesforce suggested me that I ask questions here as well. And this is what I got: a 2 downvote. 
I understand yall are experts and I am new but I really needed answers to my questions otherwise I would not have created this account here and added. 

Whoever downvote, I wish they contributed something positive to my question.